# How to make a program that would detect the same characters within two strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops

so i made this but when i enter a string it would only detect one character
and it wont convert the entered string to lower case too

```
    Dim readme, readme2 As String
    Dim j, i As Integer 
    Dim Compare As Integer
    readme = TextBox1.Text
    readme2 = TextBox2.Text

    readme.ToLower.Substring(i, readme.Length)
    readme2.ToLower.Substring(j, readme2.Length)


    For i = 0 To readme.Length

        For j = 0 To readme2.Length

            If readme = readme2 Then
                Compare = +1

            End If
        Next
    Next


    Label4.Text = Compare`enter code here`
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. You cannot apply a method to a string and expects that string to change in response to the inner operations of that method.
You need to reassign the result of the operation to the same string that you have used to call the method

```
readme = readme.ToLower()
readme2 = readme2.ToLower()
```

The second part of your question is more confused, are you trying to count the number of equal chars in the same position?

In that case your loop should be

```
Dim maxLenToCheck = Math.Min(readme.Length, readme2.Length)
For i = 0 To maxLenToCheck - 1
    If readme(i) = readme2(i) Then
        Compare += 1
    End If
Next
```

In that loop you set always the Compare to 1, the correct syntax to increment the Compare variable is

```
Compare += 1
```

Following your comment below, then I presume that your loop should be written as

```
Dim Compare = 0
For i = 0 To readme.Length - 1
    for j = 0 to readme2.Length -1 
        If readme(i) = readme2(j) AndAlso _
           Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(readme(i)) Then
            Compare += 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: yep trying to count the number of equal chars. but not in the same position

Comment: So if you have two strings: readme="This is a Test" readme2= "This should be tryed before", what is the output expected? What are the characters that you want to count as equals? For example the letter s is present 3 times in the readme and 2 times in the readme2. How many count for the letter s?

Comment: readme="This is a Test"
readme2="This should be tryed before"

____ __ a ____
____ _hould b_ _ry_d b_for_


OUTPUT: 19

Comment: Why not the second `h` in `should`?

Comment: forgot to count that hahaha the output is 20 then

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the solution by Steve, the author wants to know the count of letters occurring in both strings, ignoring case and white spaces.

By my count, however, the solution should be 21, not 20.  Here is a solution using LINQ that also gives visual feedback on where those letters are located:

[image: Solution via LINQ w/ Visual Feedback]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Class LetterCount

        Public Letter As Char
        Public Count As Integer

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Letter & " : " & Count
        End Function

    End Class

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = "This is a Test"
        TextBox2.Text = "This should be tryed before"
        RichTextBox1.ReadOnly = True
        RichTextBox1.Font = New Font("MS Courier", 14) ' monospaced font
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RichTextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf

        Dim charsA As New List(Of Char)(TextBox1.Text.ToLower.ToCharArray.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)))
        Dim charsB As New List(Of Char)(TextBox2.Text.ToLower.ToCharArray.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)))

        Dim DistinctCommonLetters = (From A In charsA, B In charsB Where A = B Select A).Distinct
        Dim DistinctCounts =
            From Letter In DistinctCommonLetters, C In charsA.Concat(charsB)
            Where C = Letter
            Group By Letter Into Group
            Select New LetterCount With {.Letter = Letter, .Count = Group.Count}
        Dim TotalMatches = DistinctCounts.Sum(Function(x) x.Count)

        ListBox1.DataSource = DistinctCounts.ToList
        Label1.Text = "TotalMatches: " & TotalMatches
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim LC As LetterCount = ListBox1.SelectedItem

        RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black

        Dim index As Integer = RichTextBox1.Find(LC.Letter, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        While index <> -1
            RichTextBox1.Select(index, 1)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
            index = RichTextBox1.Find(LC.Letter, index + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```